# Upgrade the existing drivers to newer version of drivers using C# application

Tags: c#, drivers

I wanted to verify the drivers available in work PC and upgrade if the drivers are previous old versions. The latest drivers were always present in the latest trunk.The driver folder has 3 files(*.sys,*.inf and *.cat files). The hardware is installed in one of the PCI Slot. Should work on Windows 7 & XP operating systems.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 C# 3.5. Please anyone help me with the idea of automating by installing the drivers to the hardware avoidng the manual installation every time the drivers changed.

Background:
I was using Devcon application to find the hardware connected to the computer and could check the driver revision by comparing the .sys files from the system32 folder and the latest driver in the project folder, if this does not match then try to enable and restart the PCI using devcon after copying the latest .sys and inf files in system32/drivers and inf folders respectively. This is not working for the latest drivers we have right now.

Thanks
Venu

Comment: If you package the drives in an MSI or other installer package, then you can simply package the latest versions in an installer with a higher version number. The client can check the installer to see if it is a higher version than the last installer it ran (registry key lookup or similar based on previous install) and then, if it is a newer version, simply run the installer. That's the simplest way I can think of. Note that SCCM is an administrative alternative to this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/configuration-manager-2012.aspx

Comment: Hi, I downlaoded the wondows driver kit and got the latest Devcon.exe. This worked for me.

Comment: Post that as your answer then - you can then accept the answer and earn points for it! To help future visitors, remember to include the original version of DevCon, and the new version number.

Comment: Please provide me the details..how you have done using devcon.exe..@Venu